# Novel about a young botanist from a puritanical regime who is sent to study with an unconventional (and possibly immortal) woman

Tags: story-identification, immortality

I read this around the mid-1980s -- no later than 1986 -- as a hardback I checked out from a public library in Indiana. I think I ran across it again, in another library, about a decade later, and at least glanced through it to refresh my memory.

**Plot Points:**

1. The story is set some time in the future. Technology does not seem to have progressed from the level of the 1980s (or whenever this was originally written) -- if anything, it may have regressed several decades, at least in terms of what's available to the "average citizen." Offhand, I don't recall much (if any) mention of such things as televisions, computers, jet planes, microwave ovens, spy satellites, etc. -- but the protagonist's native culture does have printed books and railroad networks and research labs and things like that. I don't remember if anyone ever goes into detail about, say, a nuclear war or some other catastrophe having happened generations earlier and caused severe setbacks, but something along those lines may have been mentioned as an excuse for why the future of this book looks so much like the past. (Say, around the level of the USA in the early decades of the 20th Century).
2. The main viewpoint character is a young man who has been raised in a puritanical and authoritarian culture. For instance, he takes very seriously the rule that you shouldn't have sex outside of marriage, and I think there can be harsh penalties for disobeying that rule, but I don't remember what those penalties would be. My impression is that this culture is a nation-state which dominates much (if not all) of what used to be the United States of America, but that large area is now called something else, and their government may dominate other portions of North America, as well. I believe the protagonist's first name is "Nick" (possibly short for "Nicholas"). I could be wrong, but I will call him "Nick" as I go along. As we meet him, he's been trained in botany or some related field. Perhaps the equivalent of a bachelor's degree, anyway -- but I don't remember whether anyone talks about college degrees per se.
3. In the first chapter, Nick is going westward by railroad, and ends up sitting in a compartment with a beautiful young woman who feels she is being forced into an unwanted marriage with a much older man. She tries to persuade Nick that the two of them could elope and get married before anyone could stop her. He is hideously embarrassed by the whole idea. I'm not sure if what she was suggesting would be "legally binding" in this imaginary culture, or if she needed the consent of a parent or legal guardian or something, but was hoping to gloss over that. At any rate, Nick turns her down. She's unhappy about this. I don't think we ever see her again after that first chapter.
4. Nick has been sent far away from his home turf to serve a sort of apprenticeship with a woman who seems to live alone, out in a forested region. I think somewhere in the Pacific Northwest. (Oregon, Washington, thereabouts?) She is supposed to have a unique degree of expertise in certain things -- related to botany. I'm not sure if anything we'd call "genetic engineering" was involved in whatever her special achievements were. She also has an odd reputation. At any rate, The Powers That Be have made some sort of deal with her to have her train Nick in some of the things that she is believed to understand better than anyone else. I shall call her Female Scientist.
5. It quickly becomes clear that Female Scientist is not a big believer in the current Official Doctrine on various things, including the concept of strict celibacy outside of marriage. She and Nick become lovers. He also notices that her apparent physical age fluctuates -- perhaps because of using makeup; perhaps for other reasons. Sometimes she could pass for a fresh-faced 18 or 20; other times she looks roughly twice that age. I *think* it eventually is revealed that she has access to some sort of biochemical concoction which basically serves as a "fountain of youth." As long as she keeps using the stuff, it will be a long, long time (if ever) before her body just "naturally" dies of simple old age. (Which does not mean she couldn't be maimed or killed by physical trauma.) I think she offers to share the stuff with Nick.
6. A pair of teenagers are also introduced and become romantically involved with each other. I think the teenage boy is the son or foster son of Female Scientist. Several chapters into the narrative, he meets a girl about his age (around sixteen, I think) who ends up seducing him one night. There's a detailed love scene (showing us his perspective, but written in the third person.)
7. Female Scientist and her friends (including the teenage girl's parents) are part of some underground network which is doing things which the government would dislike if it knew all that was going on -- but I don't recall that anything resembling "a violent revolution" was on the agenda. It may just be that certain lines of research are forbidden by the regime. Somewhere along the line, Nick becomes aware of whatever it is these people are up to, and (at least implicitly) agrees not to blow the whistle on them.
8. Except! Word comes that a female VIP -- the same person who sent Nick out to the Northwest in the first place -- wants to have a face-to-face interview with Nick. At this point, it's probably been at least a year or two since he arrived. Female Scientist is terrified that when they start asking him all sorts of pointed questions about any suspicious activities he's seen, his face will give it away that there is, in fact, something clandestine or subversive going on that he doesn't want to talk about. Because he has a painfully honest face -- he'd make a hopeless poker player.
9. Nick tries to convince her that this is not necessarily the end of the world for them, because in his adolescent days he sometimes managed to tell simple lies without anyone catching on. The author then makes it clear to us (in what I think was the final paragraph of that scene, and possibly of the entire chapter) that Nick is, for once, *lying through his teeth* about those alleged *previous* achievements in the field of deception. (He's trying to get in some practice before the big interview, I suppose.)
10. In the interview, Nick pursues a strategy of admitting to *one* breach of their culture's laws and/or moral rules of conduct (if there's any difference?) in hopes of successfully pretending that this particular sin is *all* that he and his lover are guilty of. In other words, he admits they've been sleeping together for some time now, without bothering to get married. The attraction between them just got stronger and stronger, and there was hardly anyone else around to socialize with after a hard day's work, and it just sort of happened. When he's done with this carefully limited confession, the woman who is conducting the interview says something along these lines: "You spin a convincing tale, Nick. One could almost say 'practiced.'" Strongly indicating that she figures he's been rehearsing this, and that what she's just heard might only be the tip of the iceberg.
11. That seems to be as far as my memory goes. I am sure there were more chapters after that, with the government's suspicions becoming more and more of a problem, but I don't remember just what happened as a result. I don't think Nick or his lover died tragically (because I think that sad fact would stick in my mind, in a general sort of way), but I don't remember if they fled from North America to some other nation, or found some other way to shake the authorities off their trail, or what. If I'm right about Female Scientist having a "fountain of youth," that may be relevant to whatever ended up happening.

Does anyone think this sounds familiar?

Comment: A very detailed and well-done question! I am sure that if I had read the book, I would have remembered it from your description. Sadly, I have not.

Comment: You've slung a bounty on this, but you haven't added any additional detail since the question was first asked. You could improve it by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/20774) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: I'm thinking this is probably not the book, but In the Garden of Iden by Kage Baker does fit some of the points in your description. Immortal female botanist, lover called Nicholas, but it takes place in England and was published in 1997.

Comment: Just some cursory searching, have you checked the following two options: The Chrysalids by John Wyndham or Where Late the Sweet Birds Sang by Kate Wilhelm